# When buying a computer for Ubuntu, what should I look for?

Tags: windows, mac, intel, compatibility, amd-processor

I am buying a computer with the main intent of running Ubuntu, would I get the best compatibility and performance with a Windows based computer or a Mac based computer?

---

If it runs better on Windows based machines:

- Which manufacturer (Dell, HP, ...) has the best compatibility with Ubuntu?
- Does Ubuntu run on the Intel iX series as well as it does on the AMD series?
- Are there any problems running Ubuntu on an AMD processor?

---

If it runs better on Mac based machines:

- Does Ubuntu support Thunderbolt? Will it support Thunderbolt in 13.10?
- How good is the support for the hardware peripherals? Network Card, Graphics Card, ...

---

General questions about both:

- Are SSD's recommended or not recommended? Should you not use a Swap partition with an SSD?
- What is the maximum amount of RAM Ubuntu-64 bit can handle?
- Does Ubuntu have support for quad+ core processors?

---

Edit:

I am interested in getting a Desktop (so if it were a Mac it would be the iMac). I would want to spend less than $1500 US.

Comment: laptop? desktop? budget?

Comment: @Kendor see edit

Comment: Hi John, I suggest you use the search option. There are many questions related to what hardware to buy when using Ubuntu.